# Allow user to load their data via CSV or use a sample dataset

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building a Shiny app that consists of

1. A `fileInput` for the user to upload a CSV of transactions
2. An `actionButton` that lets the user test the app with a pre-built dataset (i.e.  without them having to load their own data).
3. A `verbatimTextOutput` that prints a preview of the dataset they're using and
4. Various plot and charts built using their selected dataset

If the user uploads a file, that dataset should become the "master" `transactions` dataset to feed the rest of the app.  If they then click the "load sample data" button, *that* datset should turn into the "master" `transactions` dataset. (Extrapolate this idea to multiple alternations between them uploading data and clicking the button)

I can get this to work as follows:

```
# app.R    

library(data.table)
library(shiny)

# UI
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fileInput(inputId='fi_file', label='Choose CSV File', accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv')),
  actionButton(inputId="ab_loadSampleTransactions", label="Load Sample Transactions"),
  verbatimTextOutput("vto_transactions")
))


# Server
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # When the user uploads a file, print it
  observeEvent(input$fi_file, {
    transactions <- read.csv(input$fi_file$datapath)
    output$vto_transactions <- renderPrint(transactions)
  })

  # When the user clicks the button for sample transactions, print them
  observeEvent(input$ab_loadSampleTransactions, {
    transactions <- data.table(ID=c(1,2,3), Amount=c(100, 150, 125))
    output$vto_transactions <- renderPrint(transactions)
  })

  # More logic involving the transactions dataset
  # ...

})

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, this is inefficient because it requires me to load the `transactions` dataset twice in order to display it **and** do future logic with it. I think I need to do something reactive here, but I can't figure out how since I have two separate methods for loading the data.  Help?

Comment: Just use a global variable to store the dataset and then you can reuse it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333399/are-there-global-variables-in-r-shiny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use global variables like the suggestion in the comment says.

Use `reactiveValues`.  It sounds like you don't need this variable to be "global" in the sense that it needs to be shared with the UI and other files -- it just needs to be global within the server, correct? In that case, you can use `reactiveValues` and those variables can be accessed and set anywhere in your server