# shinyapps.io not sharing global variables in the same application/session

Tags: r, shiny, global-variables

quite strange behaviour, no idea how to handle it - sorry the code is not reproducible, but basically on Shiny Pro i have a global variable to check what items are being processed. All users read and write from the list to avoid duplication.
It is correctly placed above the Shiny Server

```
if (!exists("taken")) taken  = list()
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {...
```

the calls to the list and updates are handled as they should (with <<-) yet it **sometimes** fails to scope it globally. Even when I open 2 instances for the same user not always they see the list, even less often if I open 2 different users instances. But they sometimes can see the list after few records, it just catches up. If it was every time I could understand, but not occasional. Of course when a user does not see the list they create their own instance of the list.

How do you handle a shared items list that all users update and read from? Would you just use the same method or are there any better, more fool proof concepts?

Comment: i suggest you create an empty list `taken` globally, and just overwrite it during process later in `server` ?

Comment: do you mean just add values there? I thought it would be sufficient placeholder and if 'taken' s not visible as empty shell would it make any difference if it had one row? This one should create it, isnt it?  if (!exists("taken")) taken  = list()

Comment: i meant somthing like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334102/6779509) ie. you can define global variables in `global.R` for global scope

Comment: I started with it, but it did not work as well, so i moved above the server - no difference and from scoping perspective as well it is not relevant (as long as I do not use it in ui.r